# listoperation.pop in aerospike removing complete list instead of removing item from particular index

Tags: java, aerospike

ListOperation.pop(binName, metaInfo.getIndex())

can anyone help with this i'm using default write policy

as per doc Create list pop operation.
Server returns item at specified index and removes item from list bin.

public static Operation pop(String binName, int index, CTX... ctx) {

```
return CDT.createOperation(POP, Operation.Type.CDT_MODIFY, binName, ctx, index);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Key myKey = new Key("test", "testset", "mykey");
String binName = "myList";
ListPolicy lPolicy = new ListPolicy(ListOrder.UNORDERED, ListWriteFlags.DEFAULT);
client.delete(null,myKey);  //Start clean for test

client.operate(null, myKey, ListOperation.append(lPolicy, binName, Value.get(10))); 
client.operate(null, myKey, ListOperation.append(lPolicy, binName, Value.get(5))); 
client.operate(null, myKey, ListOperation.append(lPolicy, binName, Value.get(15))); 
client.operate(null, myKey, ListOperation.append(lPolicy, binName, Value.get(20))); 

System.out.println("My List: "+ client.get(null, myKey)); 

client.operate(null, myKey, ListOperation.pop(binName, 1) );  //Pop at index 1, (value = 5)

System.out.println("My List after pop: "+ client.get(null, myKey));
```

Output:

```
My List: (gen:4),(exp:428342885),(bins:(myList:[10, 5, 15, 20]))
My List after pop: (gen:5),(exp:428342885),(bins:(myList:[10, 15, 20]))
```